# Writing a Linux Keyboard Driver

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, hardware

I run Ubuntu, and recently bought an HP Wireless 800 keyboard and mouse.
They are not compatible with Linux by default.
Fortunately, some legend wrote [this](https://github.com/JohnJohanssonChalmers/hp_wireless_keyboard) utility that allows the keyboard to (mostly) work with Linux. My issue now is that when I start typing on the keyboard, it hangs my computer for a few seconds while my laptop's keyboard does not do the same.

What I want to do, is to try and improve the utility to remove the lag. My issue is that I don't know where to start. I can code C, but I've never done a keyboard driver before. Could someone please start me off in the right direction, as in where to learn about how keyboards interact with the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this isn't what you want to hear, seriously, go buy a decent keyboard that speaks standard USB HID protocol. The driver you've linked is a huge hack that's routing events back and forth through a sloppily written userspace driver, and is likely to have inherent latency you can't really get rid of, aside from the bugs in the code.

If you really want to do a good driver for this, it will be a major research project involving figuring out the protocol from the above code and possibly further experimentation, and involving figuring out the proper Linux driver layer for this and writing code for it. That's not to say it's undoable, but there are much more interesting things you could be doing.